# C# Datetimepicker Way to Stop Validation

Tags: c#, validation, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker with format dd.MM.yyyy when i have, for example, date 14.02.2011, save it and then want to enter 31.12.2011 then datetimepicker validator doesnt allow me to enter 31 because of month 02 inside,so it set automatically 29 in the datetimepicker.

In this case, i have to go to change a month and then back to change a day, is there a way to switch off this validation?

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` does not allow “invalid” dates. It will automatically change an invalid date to a valid date. When you type 31 into the dd field when MM is set to 02, then that would be an “invalid” date, so it is changed. If the dd was 31 and you changed MM to 02, then the dd would also change. I would guess you would have to inherit and implement you own DTP to disable the validating. I do not think there is a property that allows the user to set invalid dates.

Answer (score 0):

You have set a `Value` (DateTime) for the control and are now trying to change its elements one at a time, such that an intermediate value is invalid.

Assuming you are talking about the .Net Framework class (System.Windows.Forms), before capture (re)starts, you can use the `ResetText()` method or set the `Value` or `Text` property to an appropriate starting value for your use case.  Otherwise, instead of allowing separate editing of `Value.Day`, `.Month` and `.Year`, capture the full text representation of the date and update the control's `Text` property afterwards.